# Mongo - Select document not having a particular key value pair

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is a sample document in the collection
The collection consists of multiple documents like the below document with variable array elements in "genericParams".-

```
"currentState" : {
                "genericParams" : [
                    {
                        "key" : "sms_email_count",
                        "value" : 3
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "first_sms_email_time",
                        "value" : NumberLong("1450691202568")
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "second_sms_email_time",
                        "value" : NumberLong("1450691202568")
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "third_sms_email_time",
                        "value" : NumberLong("1450691202568")
                    },
                    {
                        "key" : "manual_refund_processed",
                        "value" : "false"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

I want to get get all such documents where the "key" is not equal to "manual_refund_processed".
At the same time i want all elements of the "genericParms" array thats why i did not use `$unwind`.
What i have tried -

1. `"currentState.genericParams.key": { $exists: true, $ne: "manual_refund_processed"  }`
2. `"currentState.genericParams.key": { $exists: true, $nin: [ "manual_refund_processed" ] }`

Comment: So what is the problem? The sample document will not be returned since that value exists, and that's what you are asking for. Are you instead expecting the document but not that particular array entry? What do you expect?

Comment: I expect to get all documents not having that particular array entry.Unwind can be used then ?

Comment: What do you think this has to do with `$unwind`? What do you think documents are? Your example has only **one** "document". There are "sub-documents" in the array entries. Which is what I asked you is that is what you meant. *"..the document but not that particular array entry?"*

Comment: The collection consists of multiple documents like the above document with variable array elements in "genericParams".

Comment: @BlakesSeven understood?

Comment: Not really. I suspect you mean to return the arrays of each document but not the array elements that contain the key you are asking for. That is what the answers given ( if not with great explanation ) are doing, but it's not very clear in the way you are phrasing if that is what you mean. The preference would of course be `$filter`, as long as you have MongoDB 3.2 available. Or `$map` and `$setDifference` or even `$redact` for MongoDB 2.6 or greater ( most likely ). Generally try to stay away from `$unwind` where possible, due to the overhead it introduces ( ie document copy per array entry )

Comment: Just shut this question down please and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238554/mongo-select-document-having-particular-key-value-pair-but-not-having-other-ke , have added more details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filters: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/

```
        $filter: {
           input: "$genericParams",
           as: "genericParam",
           cond: { $ne: [ "$$genericParam.key", "manual_refund_processed" ] }
        }
```

Comment: Possibly what the OP is asking, but the syntax here to select the array is not really correct, and also lacks context of the full aggregate statement in demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet will give you exact result. Suppose your data is stored in collection named **state** so

```
db.state.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$currentState.genericParams"},
{$match:{"currentState.genericParams.key":{$ne:"manual_refund_processed"}}},
{$group:{_id:"$_id", genericParams:{$push:"$currentState.genericParams"}}},
{$project:{_id:0, currentState: { genericParams:"$genericParams"}}}
]).pretty()
```

or

```
db.state.aggregate([
{$project: 
{_id:0, currentState:{genericParams:
{ $filter:
{ input: "$currentState.genericParams", as: "genericParam", cond:
{ $ne: [ "$$genericParam.key", "manual_refund_processed" ]}}}}}}
]).pretty()
```

output is:

```
{
    "currentState" : {
        "genericParams" : [
            {
                "key" : "sms_email_count",
                "value" : 3
            },
            {
                "key" : "first_sms_email_time",
                "value" : NumberLong("1450691202568")
            },
            {
                "key" : "second_sms_email_time",
                "value" : NumberLong("1450691202568")
            },
            {
                "key" : "third_sms_email_time",
                "value" : NumberLong("1450691202568")
            }
        ]
    }
}
```